# Having problems with CORS at GCP. Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, next.js

I'm trying to upload files from my NextJs app, but Google doesn't want to allow me uploading it via SignedUrl with NextJs API. (It does work with S3). Also, I tested it on postman and it allows me to upload files. Weird.

Getting SIGNEDURL:

```
const options = {
  version: 'v4',
  action: 'write',
  expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000,
  contentType: 'application/octet-stream'
}

const url = await storage
  .bucket(BUCKET_NAME) // .env variable with the bucket
  .file(path)
  .getSignedUrl(options)
```

Using URL to download files and track UploadProgress via axios:

```
axios({
url, // signed url from the function above
method: 'PUT',
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
},
data, // new FormData with the files on it
onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
  const percentCompleted = Math.round(
    (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
  )
  updateProgressCallback({ file, percentCompleted }) // to keep track of the upload progress
}})
```

Also, here you have the GCP bucket cors.json config:

```
[
  {
   "origin": ["*"], // it is for testing purposes, later i will write the domain
   "responseHeader": ["*"],
   "method": ["GET","POST","HEAD","DELETE"],
   "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

Comment: You are using the HTTP PUT method, but the CORS methods do not include PUT.

Comment: True, after allowing it, I keep getting the same error:
```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'GOGLESIGNEDURL' http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Also, it works well with Postman and PUT request.

Comment: Postman does not enforce CORS, the browser does. Postman is good for validating the rest of the API call.